# This resource is not available for Workplace applications in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I want to search user by name in the workplace integration. So I'm using graph API and sending this request

```
GET  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=jay&type=user&access_token={access_token}&appsecret_proof={sha256 hash of access token and app secret}
```

But it gives me an error saying

```
{
  "error": {
      "message": "(#3) This resource is not available for Workplace applications.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 3,
      "fbtrace_id": "D7Zu8E7sIkY"
  }
}
```

Somebody, please help me, **My aim is to find the user's information by their name instead of email id or user id.**

P.S. I've given all the permissions to my integration.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in workplace you can't search users by name, but only by id or email address.

In order to search a user by email the call is

```
GET /scim/v1/Users?filter=userName%20eq%20%22juliusc@example.com%22 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.facebook.com 
Authorization: Bearer {your access token}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I can searce specific user by `scim` API, but what If I want to search user by name. There isn't anything to do such thing??

Comment: no, sorry it is impossible to do directly with Graph API